# initWith not found after upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin version to 7.0.0-beta02

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to `7.0.0-beta02`, `initWith` cannot be found.

In `build.gradle.kts`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ....
    }
    dependencies {
-        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha14")
+        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta02")
    }
}
```

then in `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```
    debug {
        ...
    }
    create("enterprise") {
        initWith(getByName("debug")) // <------ This is not found!
    }
```

If this method is removed from the latest version, then what will be the equivalent of `initWith`?

Comment: This is currently a known issue - see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186798050#comment4 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188853147 for more info